# How do I schedule the recording of a live Youtube stream to watch later?

Tags: youtube, schedule, stream, video-recording

I wanted to record live church streams that I cannot watch live when they take place and that are not originally archived by the church themselves. What software can I use to accomplish this on a scheduled basis?

Comment: Related and maybe part of a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040798/how-do-you-use-youtube-dl-to-download-live-streams-that-are-live